# List overwriting previous added Objects when a new Object is added

Tags: c#, list

I'm looping through some logic for a program I'm making that reads text through a .txt file and every time I get to the place where the algorithm adds a Class Object I created it works but then the next time it hits it the previous object gets its data changed to the object currently being added and so on.

Here is a Snippet of code for preface this is inside While loop and nested in 3 if statements.

**Question**: Why is it overwriting all the other entries?

My logic is 100% working I ran tests on it for over 10 hours with many breakpoints also please go easy on me I'm semi proficient at C#

```
    if (Att == a1)
    {
        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.Eid = Eid;
        s1.Name = Name;
        s1.Attempt1 = att1;
        AllStudents.Add(s1);
        //AllStudents.Add(new Student(Eid,Name, att1));

        Eid = line;
        Att = "";
        qnum = 1;
        counter = 1;
    }
```

Here is my Student class

```
public class Student
    {
        public string Eid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] Attempt1 { get; set; }
        public string[] Attempt2 { get; set; }
        public string[] Attempt3 { get; set; }
        public string[] Att1filler = { "n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "n/a" };
        public string[] Att2filler = {"n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a"};
        public string[] Att3filler = {"n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a","n/a"};

        public int FinalGrade { get; set; }
        public int Grade1 { get; set; }
        public int Grade2 { get; set; }
        public int Grade3 { get; set; }
        public int Grade4 { get; set; }

        public Student()
        {
            FinalGrade = 0;
            Attempt1 = Att1filler;
            Attempt2 = Att2filler;
            Attempt3 = Att3filler;
        }
        public Student(string Eagid, string name, string[] Att1)
        {
            Eid = Eagid;
            Name = name;
            Attempt1 = Att1;
            Attempt2 = Att2filler;
            Attempt3 = Att3filler;
            FinalGrade = 0;
        }
        public Student(string Eagid, string name, string[] Att1, string[] Att2)
        {
            Eid = Eagid;
            Name = name;
            Attempt1 = Att1;
            Attempt2 = Att2;
            Attempt3 = Att3filler;
            FinalGrade = 0;
        }
        public Student(string Eagid, string name, string[] Att1, string[] Att2, string[] Att3)
        {
            Eid = Eagid;
            Name = name;
            Attempt1 = Att1;
            Attempt2 = Att2;
            Attempt3 = Att3;
            FinalGrade = 0;
        }
}
```

And finally this is how I declared my List

```
 public List<Student> AllStudents = new List<Student>();
```

also the `AllStudents.add(new Student(Eid,Name, att1));` is from another solution i found that still did not work for me.

Comment: What's the code in your loop?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. what you say is whenever you add an object to your list the Length of the list does not change ? and the previous object updated? do you check the Length of you list each time you add ??

Comment: the length will increase and the new student is added but all the previous students data are changed to the newest Student added

Comment: The code in my loop is essentially just logic to pull data out of a txt file it all works fine and dandy its just adding that's currently not wanting to work correctly if you need to see more of the code I could add slightly more

Comment: I GOT IT Thank you guys for the zippy responses much appreciated all the attempt arrays were initialized outside the Loop which lead to the reference being passed instead of just the values!

Comment: So please remove your question or Update the code and explain the problem for futures

Comment: I'm new here so Let me know if the answer below is suitable if not I'll remove the post thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Learned my lesson of passing by references vs passing by value. make sure if your algorithm is looping that anything that is initialized by new and is used inside the loop is re-initialized inside  the loop so you don't just pass the same reference for each object.(sorry if this answer isn't 100% I'm running on 2 hours of sleep trying to get this project done!)